# Xcode Cloud Testing fails to archive project

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcode-cloud

I have errors with Xcode cloud testing while archiving.

Issues are all related to CocoaPods dependencies:

`unable to open file (in target "Alamofire" in project "Pods")`

`missing module map file: '/Volumes/workspace/repository/Pods/Target Support Files/Alamofire/Alamofire.modulemap`

Looks like pods are not being installed on archiving.

It works well locally.

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is here for CocoaPods, Carthage or SPM :
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/making-dependencies-available-to-xcode-cloud#Use-a-Custom-Build-Script-to-Install-a-Third-Party-Dependency-or-Tool

Answer (score 7):

Xcode Cloud temporary build environment doesn't include third party tools like CocoaPods. But you can include them using post clone script. Here are the steps if you are using CocoaPods.

1. Create a directory `ci_scripts` at the root of your project.
2. Add a file `ci_post_clone.sh` and save it in the ci_scripts directory.
3. Open `Terminal` and make your script executable be running `chmod +x ci_post_clone.sh` in `ci_scripts` directory.
4. Edit the `ci_post_clone.sh` in any text editor and copy the following.

   ```
    # !/bin/sh

    # Install CocoaPods using Homebrew.
    brew install cocoapods

    # Install dependencies you manage with CocoaPods.
    pod install
   ```
5. Commit and push `ci_post_clone.sh`.

Comment: brew is not installed on their cloud machines ...

Comment: brew is available, I tried it and it works.

Comment: @YaroslavDukal Yeah it stoped working from couple of weeks. It was working earlier and even brew commands are mentioned in the apple docs here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/making-dependencies-available-to-xcode-cloud#Use-a-Custom-Build-Script-to-Install-a-Third-Party-Dependency-or-Tool . As it's still in beta so there might be some changes or bug

Comment: It worked.. but I am disappointed, build takes forever with all this post install things... My mac book pro compiles it way faster and does not have to install 3rd party dependencies each build .. Not recommended to use that.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation suggested way of setting this up is terrible - it has no versioning, and it takes a lot of time to install through brew.
The best way is having a `Gemfile` that declares the dependencies at the root of your repo, ie:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'cocoapods'
gem 'fastlane'
```

Then `bundle install` it to lock the versions of the tools on a `Gemfile.lock` (you should version both files in your repo).

On your `ci_scripts/ci_post_clone.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/sh

#1 - You can't install gems to the system gem path without sudo, so create a local one
echo ">>> SETUP LOCAL GEM PATH"
echo 'export GEM_HOME=$HOME/gems' >>~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH=$HOME/gems/bin:$PATH' >>~/.bash_profile
export GEM_HOME=$HOME/gems
export PATH="$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH"

#2 - Install the actual bundler version you bundled locally with, so you don't have any surprises
echo ">>> INSTALL REQUIRED BUNDLER VERSION"
gem install bundler -v "$(grep -A 1 "BUNDLED WITH" ../Gemfile.lock | tail -n 1)" --install-dir $GEM_HOME

#3 - Let bundler download the locked version of cocoapods, fastlane, and whatever other tools you need
echo ">>> INSTALL DEPENDENCIES"
bundle install

#4 - Finally you can run the bundled pod binary to install your dependencies
echo ">>> INSTALL PODS"
bundle exec pod install
```

Also, consider commiting your `Pods` folder to avoid the need to run cocoapods at all. Or at least gitignore only large binaries (i.e Twilio, WebRTC, etc). This also protects you from deleted repos or offline services providers